# NAT and vmware 2.x

Tags: nat, vmware-server

Usually with vmware server 1.x I used NAT mode so that I can reach guest from host and it did work well.

Some days ago I upgrade to vmware server 2.x and I noticed that with NAT mode now I cannot reach guest from host (while guest can reach host).

Is this the expected behaviour with vmware server 2.x?

I used NAT because I need to reach guest from host with cable unplugged and NAT mode did permit me to do the job

Thanks in advance for your replies

Answer (score 1):

According to the VMWare 2.x documentation, NAT should operate the same way in 2.x.

Try doing a tracert to the guest from the host to see where the traffic is going.  My guess is it is going out the LAN interface rather then the VMware NAT interface.  Also check that firewall settings on the guest haven't changed.